# MySQL copying a column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello so I have two tables and I want to copy one column from table1 to table2.

```
SET @m=0;
SELECT column INTO @m FROM table1;
UPDATE table2 SET column = @m;
```

Basically I tried to insert into the column in table2 the values from column in table1. What am I doing wrong?

LE: I tried the INSERT INTO and it worked in the end but it inserted the values after my desired rows. Basically all my rows had the values 0 and it created another set of rows with the correct values.

Comment: Do you have any other columns in your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is Correct but when you are copying you should take care about types ... 
**types** should be compatible to each other

```
INSERT INTO table (column)
  SELECT a_column 
  FROM a_table
                       --- optional (multiple) JOINs
                       --- and WHERE
                       --- and GROUP BY      
                       --- any complex SELECT query
```

Comment: Do you mean compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax: `INSERT INTO table2 (column) SELECT column FROM table1`

Don't need VALUES and parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this to one row you could use a stored procedure.

```
SELECT column INTO myvar FROM table1

INSERT INTO table2 (column) VALUES (myvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column) (SELECT column FROM table1)
```